# Support for Ctrl+C / Ctrl+Z at " answer=$( while ! head -c 1 | grep -i '[ny]' ; do true ; done ) "

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh, posix

To get a user's `[Y/N]` decision I am using a "yesno" function, which contains a loop:

```
answer=$( while ! head -c 1 | grep -i '[ny]' ; do true ; done )
```

However, this loop is blocking a console and impossible to terminate by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>  or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> . Adding stuff like `[\x03]` (ascii for  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ) or `[\x1A]` (ascii for  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> ) does not help either. How to add this feature, while preserving the POSIX compatibility and without relying on other tools?

```
#!/bin/sh

yesno () {
    printf "$1 [Y/N] "
    old_stty_cfg=$( stty -g )
    stty raw -echo
    answer=$( while ! head -c 1 | grep -i '[ny]' ; do true ; done )
    stty "$old_stty_cfg"
    if printf "$answer" | grep -iq "^y" ; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

if yesno "Question?" ; then
    printf "yes\n"
    return 0
else
    printf "no\n"
    return 1
fi
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why don't you use `read`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. This is a part of larger script which didn't use `read` / `awk` anywhere, and I don't know if there are certain implementations of them which work differently on some systems - so I hope to add Ctrl+C / Ctrl+Z by relying on already used `head` / `grep` / `printf`

Comment: `read` is a special builtin, so you don't need to worry about per-OS implementations, just about whether POSIX guarantees that the shell will provide the minimum amount of functionality you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments about this solution and its' POSIX compatibility - will be really appreciated !

```
#!/bin/sh
enter=$( printf '\015' )
ctrl_c=$( printf '\003' )
ctrl_x=$( printf '\030' )
ctrl_z=$( printf '\032' )

yesno () {
    printf '%b [Y/N] ' "$1"
    old_stty_cfg=$( stty -g )
    stty raw -echo
    while true ; do
        answer=$( head -c 1 )
        case $answer in *"$ctrl_c"*|"$ctrl_x"*|"$ctrl_z"*)
            stty "$old_stty_cfg"
            exit 1
            ;;
            *"y"*|"Y"*)
            stty "$old_stty_cfg"
            return 0
            ;;
            *"n"*|"N"*)
            stty "$old_stty_cfg"
            return 1
            ;;
        esac
    done
}

if yesno "Question?" ; then
    printf "yes\n"
    exit 0
else
    printf "no\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `$''` is itself not POSIX-compatible syntax, and only works on extended shells.

Comment: Also, `case $answer in [Yy]*)` is *much* more efficient than a pipeline with `grep`.

Comment: I'd suggest, when your script first starts, assigning the values you want to variables you can reference again later. `ctrl_c=$(printf '\003'); ctrl_v=$(printf '\030'); ctrl_z=$(printf '\032')`. Then you can use `case $answer in *"$ctrl_c"*|*"$ctrl_v"*|*"$ctrl_z"*) ...;` to compare against those values portably and quickly.

Comment: ...the assignment is inefficient/expensive because it's launching a subshell to run `printf` in, but since you're doing it only once, it gets folded into startup cost.

Comment: BTW, in general, `printf "$1 [Y/N] "` is bad form; consider `printf '%s [Y/N] ' "$1"`, so your string's contents can't be treated as a format string (or `%b` instead of `%s` if you *want* that to be possible for backslash-escape sequences).

Comment: ...you're also going to eat a lot of performance overhead from running a subshell and then spawning an external `head` command in it over and over and over; if you *can* switch to `read`, I'd suggest doing so (though I'd need to refer to the POSIX spec to know if `-n 1` is standardized).

Comment: (BTW, for future readers -- I understand that there's been discussion of folding `$''` into future versions of the POSIX.2 specification, so just because it wasn't standardized when this comment thread was written doesn't mean it still isn't standardized when you read this!)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wrote a new version above using your suggestions, please could you take a look?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you could also write your review as a reply and I will accept it

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer -- you've written something other people could reasonably use. (That said, one last change I might make is to move the variable initializations out of function scope so they run only once no matter how many times the function is called -- they're polluting global namespace no matter what, since POSIX sh doesn't specify function-local variables, and you'd need an extension like `declare` or `local` to make variables local on non-POSIX shells anyhow). If you want clearer visual scoping, maybe name them with a prefix, like `yesno_old_tty_cfg=$(...)`

Comment: ...one little note -- previously you were `grep`ping for `^y`, the `^` anchor made the code see a `y` as affirmative only when it's at the front of the string; when you make it `case *y*)`, you accept a `y` anywhere in the string; `case y*)` would be a closer equivalent to the old code.